# RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo while adding icons to Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm designing a Navigation drawer which has icons to each item in the list. i followed [this](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html) tutorial exactly. But I'm getting a run time exception.

Here is my logcat.

```
11-12 12:15:53.767    5237-5237/com.myayubo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myayubo, PID: 5237
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myayubo/com.myayubo.Extract}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myayubo.Extract.onCreate(Extract.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here, I put only one item in the list (just to check)

Here is my `strings.xml`

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Ayubo</string>
    <string name="title_activity_maps">Map</string>
    <string name="title_activity_login">LoginActivity</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_splash">Splash</string>
    <string name="title_activity_extract_menu">ExtractMenu</string>

    <string-array name="titles">
        <item>hotel</item>
        <item>resturant</item>
        <item>wildlife</item>
    </string-array>

    <array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/ic_hotel</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_resturant</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_wildlife</item>
    </array>


    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

    <string name="action_example">Example action</string>
    <string name="title_activity_sign_up">sign_up</string>

    <string name="app_id">914777611938198</string>
    <string name="title_activity_extract">Extract</string>
</resources>
```

here is my `Extract.java` (Main Acitivity)

```
public class Extract extends ActionBarActivity {

    String[] menutitles;
    TypedArray menuIcons;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private List<RowItem> rowItems;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_extract);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        menuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slider_list);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
            RowItem items = new RowItem(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(      i, -1));
            rowItems.add(items);
        }

        menuIcons.recycle();
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), rowItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideitemListener());

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();          }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            updateDisplay(0);
        }
    }

    class SlideitemListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            updateDisplay(position);
        }
    }
        private void updateDisplay(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new hotel();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

                // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                setTitle(menutitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("Extract", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_extract, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
            default :
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***   * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered   */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**   * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during   * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...   */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Here is my `activity_extract.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/slider_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my `list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my `RowItem.java`

```
package com.myayubo;

public class RowItem {
    private String title;
    private int icon;
    public RowItem(String title, int icon) {
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

Here is my `CustomAdapter.java`

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;  List<RowItem> rowItem;

    CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItem = rowItem;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        RowItem row_pos = rowItem.get(position);

        // setting the image resource and title
        imgIcon.setImageResource(row_pos.getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowItem.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }
}
```

Here is my `hotel.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_locationhotel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my `hotel.java`

```
public class hotel extends Fragment {

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater .inflate(R.layout.hotel, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I can't identify what is happening here. I didn't really implemented a Navigation Drawer on my own before. That is why I followed exact steps in following tutorial. What should I do to run this perfectly?

-Edit-

```
Here is my `AndrdoidManifest.xml`

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myayubo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="Ayubo" >

            <!-- Intent filter should be here -->
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".sign_up"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Extract"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_extract"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

-Edit 2 (New Error)-

```
11-12 13:31:44.753  11673-11673/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myayubo, PID: 11673
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myayubo/com.myayubo.Extract}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myayubo.Extract.onCreate(Extract.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what stands on line 60 of `Extract.java`

Comment: You mean this? Log.e("Extract", "Error in creating fragment");

Comment: Why using `ActionBarActivity` . Avoid this

Comment: @Manu Line #60. Your IDE should have line numbers on the left side of your source code.

Comment: @Mike M Im using Andrdoid Studio. no line numbers

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya U mean Activity instead of ActionBarActivity ?

Comment: I followed http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html tutorial

Comment: You can turn on line numbers in the settings somewhere. You might be able to right click the left margin, and do it from that context menu. I don't recall, exactly.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. Im kind of beginer to Andrdoid. So, line number 60 means getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: Select the Extract.java file. Press `Strl` + `g`. Enter 60. Press enter. Tell us which line is that.

Comment: Can you please include your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @ Boris Strandjev , getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: @Manu: yup, I saw I just wanted to teach you how to do it easily. Can you incldue the manifest?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Manifest addded.

Comment: @Manu You should be using `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Comment: It worked Mike M.  thank u so much. All I had to do was  use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **`getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar()`** resolved the problem. Now working as expected.

Comment: Glad to hear . Move ahead

Answer (score 1):

You are using [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), which is the app compat version of activity with action bar.

Add the following attribute `android:theme=”@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light”` in the `<activity>` tag in your manifest for the `Extract` activity.

The purpose of the app compat library is to provide functionalities to older versions of the API. The thing is that Android changed their Android SDK to include ActionBar, but only Honeycomb and above. App compat `ActionBarActivity` aims at adding the Action bar functionalities on even lower versions of the API. However, in order to "activate" the existence of an action bar you need to specify a particular app compat theme for your activity.

**PS:** Also, as a disclaimer, you are overall using the kind of old concept of Action bar. Nowadays android developers are speaking of Toolbars, which need to be added in a bit different way. [Android developers](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html) describes how to add Toolbar in a detail. Keep in mind that if you go for the toolbar you will need to change the theme I requested you add, because oterwise you will get duplicated existence of action bar.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myayubo, PID: 11673
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myayubo/com.myayubo.Extract}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: See updated manifest by adding android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" . but, still not working. :(

Comment: @Manu I believe you should have gotten to the next error. Give as postscript of the question the new stacktrace

Comment: using getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar() resolved the problem. :) Thanks